# Redux Toolkit Query and pre fetching some datas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit Query to fetch datas from Audius server. The service is based on many IPFS nodes, and it is best practice to make a query of the best performing servers to which send the API requests in that particular moment. This is the function Audius API docs suggest to use in order to find the right server:

```
const sample = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  var host = await fetch('https://api.audius.co')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(j => j.data)
    .then(d => sample(d))
```

I need to get the url from this function and feed it into the function where I use the `createApi` method. 
 I wrapped the function in an async function, since it uses `await`, but I am stuck in the Promise.

```
async function getHost() {
  const sample = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  var host = await fetch('https://api.audius.co')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(j => j.data)
    .then(d => sample(d))
}
```

I don't know how to get a value as result of this function, I know how to do it with React components, using `useState` Hook, but I would not like to use it here, as I think it will slow down the process. 
 I tried to understand how to use the `createAsyncThunk` but I can't wrap my mind around it. 
The rest of the code looks like this:

```
const contentProvider = `https://discoveryprovider2.audius.co`
const audiusVersion = `/v1`
const appName = `app_name=ZION`
const baseUrl = contentProvider + audiusVersion
const section = [`/users`, `/playlists`, `/tracks`]
const search = `/search?query=`

export const audiusApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'audiusApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: `${baseUrl}` }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    // SEARCH USERS
    // https://discovery-a.mainnet.audius.radar.tech/v1/users/search?query=Brownies&app_name=EXAMPLEAPP
    searchUsers: builder.query({
      query: (searchQuery) => `${section[0]}${search}${searchQuery}${appName}`
    }), 
.........})
  }),
})



export const {
  useSearchUsersQuery,
  useGetUserQuery,
  useGetUsersFavTracksQuery,
  useGetUsersRepostsQuery,
  useGetUserMostUsedTagsQuery,
  useGetUserTracksQuery,
  useSearchPlaylistQuery,
  useGetPlaylistQuery,
  useGetPlaylistTracksQuery,
  useSearchTracksQuery,
  useTrendingTracksQuery,
  useGetTrackQuery,
  useStreamTrackQuery
} = audiusApi
```

So basically I need to place the result of the `async` function = to `contentProvider`.

I tried doing simply

```
var response = getHost() // my async function

var contentProvider = response
```

but this doesn't pass through

Hope someone can help me out with this one =).

Comment: All that depends on how you finally want to use that value, which I honestly can't really read out of your question here. You don't need `createAsyncThunk` for just getting a value, you'd only use that if you also wanted to dispatch "lifecycle actions".

Comment: I need to use the value for the fetchBaserQuery for the `createApi` redux slice which covers all the request to the Audius API. Cause the first function delivers the endpoint for the best performing server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a baseQuery with a dynamic `baseUrl`.

We have an [example on a baseQuery that uses Redux state for the baseUrl](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#constructing-a-dynamic-base-url-using-redux-state) in the docs.

That still means, you have to get the baseUrl into the store though.

Adjusting an example from [the Redux Essentials tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#fetching-data-with-createasyncthunk):

```
export const getHost = createAsyncThunk('host/getHost', async () => {
  const sample = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  return fetch('https://api.audius.co')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(j => j.data)
    .then(d => sample(d))
})

const hostSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'host',
  initialState: null,
  reducers: {
  },
  extraReducers(builder){
    builder.addCase(getHost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      return action.payload
    }
  }
})
```

Then you plug your `hostSlice.reducer` into `configureStore`:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    host: hostSlice.reducer
// more stuff you had before
  }
})
```

and dispatch the thunk:

```
dispatch(getHost())
```

Your host will be available via `getState().host` in your adjusted baseQuery then.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was actually following the tutorial but I got stuck into the export/import ... which is the same thing I am stuck now following your suggestions. I add export to `const hostSlice` and imported it as : `import { hostSlice } from "../features/audiusProvider/audiusProviderSlice";` in the store.
But then I am actually lost, in order to use `dispatch` I should  add it calling useDispatch Hook in the file I am using RTK query? sorry for my ignorance 

Comment: Depends on when and how you want to call that. You could call that just after store creation, in which case you would just do `store.dispatch(getHost())` - maybe even in your store creation file. You could also do it in a component, there it would be `const dispatch = useDispatch()` followed by `dispatch(getHost())`

Comment: I tried adding this to the store creation file :
`store.dispatch(getHost())`
`const host = store.getState().host`
`console.log(host);`
but i get `null` as a result ....
I imported `getHost` from the file where I used `createAsyncThunk` ...
I dont get where I am doing wrong =(

Comment: Well, if you log that *immediately* after starting the request, it will be `null`, because the request takes a while. Best take a look at the Redux Devtools and see the value changing from `null` to your host after a moment.

Comment: Indeed =) awesome!!! Really thanks for the help =) Much appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you well, I think you struggle with how to work with async functions.

you can easily use `async await`.

```
async function getHost() {
  const sample = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  var host = await fetch('https://api.audius.co');
  var json = await host.json();
  var data = await json.data;
  var d = await sample(data);
  
  return d;
}
```

and you can call it as

```
var result = await getHost();
 
  result.
    then(d => console.log(d));
```

Comment: In fact, i should put that `var result` inside an async func, since its using `await` am I wrong?
But then we are at the same point as before... i need to get the data from the promise into a variable. As far as I understood, to have an actual value to work with one should use useState or redux ... cause if not you are always getting a promise as response ...

Comment: I used to struggle, but now I get my head around it better, with React using useState, and even with more ease, with Redux Toolkit Query. In fact I could first create a service (as per suggested on Redux Toolkit tutos) and I could then import the data into the second service file, but I suppose there is a more agile way to do that..